# Why doesn't localeCompare work as I expect?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I try to sort array data alphabetically but I think something is not OK.

```js
var items;

// it's OK  
items = ['a', 'á'];
items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'hu'));
console.log(items); // ["a", "á"]

// it's OK, too
items = ['an', 'án'];
items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'hu'));
console.log(items); // ["an", "án"]

// hmmm, it's not
items = ['an', 'ál'];
items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'hu'));
console.log(items); // ["ál", "an"]
```

The Hungarian alphabet starts with a, á, b, c...

Any suggestion, how should I use localecompare function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there is no way to do it with `localeCompare` it seems as if you have to write your own sorter:

```
const alphabet = "aábcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function alphabetically(a, b) {
  a = a.toLowerCase(), b = b.toLowerCase();
  // Find the first position were the strings do not match
  let position = 0;
  while(a[position] === b[position]) {
      // If both are the same don't swap
      if(!a[position] && !b[position]) return 0;
      // Otherwise the shorter one goes first
      if(!a[position]) return 1;
      if(!b[position]) return -1;
      position++;
  }
  // Then sort by the characters position
  return alphabet.indexOf(a[position]) - alphabet.indexOf(b[position]);
}
```

Usable as

```
 array.sort(alphabetically);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `a` and `á` has the same `base letter`: `a`.

```
console.log('a'.localeCompare('á', 'hu', { sensitivity: 'base' })); // 0
```

The difference can be illustrated with the letters `a` and `ä` in both swedish and german:

In swedish `a` and `ä` don't have the same base letter but are infact two different letters.

```
console.log('a'.localeCompare('ä', 'sv', { sensitivity: 'base' })); // -1
```

In german `a` and `ä` have the same base letter

```
console.log('a'.localeCompare('ä', 'de', { sensitivity: 'base' })); // 0
```

Your option is to write a custom sorting algorithm as Jonas W suggested.

Comment: Its interesting that I didn't know the correct sorting of my native language ... :) And its even more interesting how that differs to others([see wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order)), really nice answer :)